# The plugin 'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qwindowsd.dll' uses incompatible Qt library (Cannot mix debug and release libraries)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt5

I am trying to create a standalone script with QGIS functionality however I continuously run into this error regarding QT platform plugin not loading "windows" not loading.

Current error code:

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Qt5\plugins" even though it was found. This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. Available platform plugins are: direct2d, minimal, offscreen, windows.

I set the `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS` environment variable in attempt to confirm that QT was looking in the right folders to look for this plugin and I got this

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Python37" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Python37/python3.dll"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from 'C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Python37/python3.dll'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Python37/python37.dll"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from 'C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Python37/python37.dll'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qdirect2d.dll"
Found metadata in lib C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qdirect2d.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "direct2d"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QWindowsDirect2DIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330498
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("direct2d")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qdirect2dd.dll"
Found metadata in lib C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qdirect2dd.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "direct2d"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QWindowsDirect2DIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": true,
    "version": 330498
}


"The plugin 'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qdirect2dd.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release libraries.)" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qminimal.dll"
Found metadata in lib C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qminimal.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330498
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qminimald.dll"
Found metadata in lib C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qminimald.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": true,
    "version": 330498
}


"The plugin 'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qminimald.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release libraries.)" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qoffscreen.dll"
Found metadata in lib C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qoffscreen.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330498
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qoffscreend.dll"
Found metadata in lib C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qoffscreend.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": true,
    "version": 330498
}


"The plugin 'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qoffscreend.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release libraries.)" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll"
Found metadata in lib C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "windows"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QWindowsIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330498
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("windows")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qwindowsd.dll"
Found metadata in lib C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qwindowsd.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "windows"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QWindowsIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": true,
    "version": 330498
}


"The plugin 'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qwindowsd.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release libraries.)" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Python37/platforms" ...
Cannot load library C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll: The specified procedure could not be found.
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll" : "Cannot load library C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Qt5\\plugins\\platforms\\qwindows.dll: The specified procedure could not be found."
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Qt5\plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: direct2d, minimal, offscreen, windows.
```

The thing I noticed was while the metadata shows that `qwindows`, `qdirect2d`, `qminimal` and `qoffscreen` all have debug set to false, the metadata for `qwindowsd`, `qdirect2dd`, `qminimald` and `qoffscreend` all have this debug setting set to `true`. Would that be causing the

> "The plugin 'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms/qwindowsd.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release libraries.)"

result after each dll?

For reference the script I was using to access QGIS using Python is the following

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = r'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Qt5\plugins'
os.environ['QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS'] = '1'
os.environ['PATH'] += r'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Qt5\bin; C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin'
sys.path.extend([r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python', r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages'])

from qgis.core import *
from PyQt5 import *


QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qgis', True)

qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

qgs.initQgis()

QGIS_project = QgsProject.instance()
print(QGIS_project)
QGIS_project.read('PATH TO QGIS PROJECT')

print(QGIS_project)
map_layers = QGIS_project.mapLayers()
print(map_layers)
raster_layer = QGIS_project.mapLayersByName('raster_test')
shapefile_layer = QGIS_project.mapLayersByName('shapefile_test')

print(raster_layer)
print(shapefile_layer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Remove the debug dlls from the platforms folder if you have any to prevent the issue of mixing debug and release builds.

So I only have the following in the platforms folder

- qdirect2d.dll
- qminimal.dll
- qoffscreen.dll
- qwindows.dll

and put the other dlls in a separate folder called DEBUG

I also modified the windows batch file to include a call to the qt5_env.bat

```
@echo off
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
call %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat
call %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass78\etc\qt5_env.bat <---- added this to the batch file

REM PATH setup
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37\Scripts
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\bin

REM QGIS setup
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis
set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python

REM GRASS setup
set GRASSBIN=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\grass78.bat
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass78\etc\python
```

Running this new python script

```
import os
import sys

# ADD THIS PRIOR TO CALLING qgis.core

os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Qt5\\plugins'
os.environ['PATH'] += ';C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\bin;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Qt5\\bin'
sys.path.extend(['C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\python', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages'])

from qgis.core import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis', True)


qgs = QgsApplication([], True)

qgs.initQgis()

# This is where you would do things

qgs.exitQgis()
```

And it worked without errors.